# install ffmpeg on amazon ecr linux python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, ffmpeg

I'm trying to install ffmpeg on docker for amazon lambda function.
Code for Dockerfile is:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  yum install gcc -y
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
RUN  yum install -y ffmpeg

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

I am getting an error:

```
 > [6/6] RUN  yum install -y ffmpeg:
#9 0.538 Loaded plugins: ovl
#9 1.814 No package ffmpeg available.
#9 1.843 Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Hi Luka, Im having the same issue... Did you find a solution?

Comment: not really, I decided to use an already made layer with ffmpeg. Other thing you can do is: make an EC2, SSH into it, install ffmpeg, zip it, download it locally and then make a layer for yourself... you can find tutorial for this on Yt if you don't get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the ffmpeg package is not available with yum package manager, I have manually installed ffmpeg and made it part of the container. Here are the steps:

1. Downloaded the static build from [here](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (the build for the `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8 image is ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz`

   [Here](https://www.maskaravivek.com/post/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ec2-running-amazon-linux/) is a bit more info on the topic.
2. Manually unarchived it in the root folder of my project (where my Dockerfile and app.py files are). I use a CodeCommit repo but this is not mandatory of course.
3. Added the following line my Dockerfile:

   ```
   COPY ffmpeg-5.1.1-amd64-static /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
   ```
4. In the `requirements.txt` I added the following line (so that the python package managed installs ffmpeg-python package):

   ```
   ffmpeg-python
   ```
5. And here is how I use it in my python code:

   ```
   import ffmpeg

   ...

   process1 = (ffmpeg
             .input(sourceFilePath)
             .output("pipe:", format="s16le", acodec="pcm_s16le", ac=1, ar="16k", loglevel="quiet")
             .run_async(pipe_stdout=True, cmd=r"/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg")
         )
   ```

   Note that in order to work, in the run method (or run_async in my case) I
   needed to specify the cmd property with the location of the ffmpeg
   executable.
6. I was able to build the container and the ffmpeg is working properly for me.

---

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY input_files ./input_files

COPY ffmpeg-5.1.1-amd64-static /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

RUN chmod 777 -R /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.lambda_handler" ]
```

Comment: Please could you link to your complete Dockerfile

Comment: @AlistairHughes it's added

Comment: I get permission denied error, even after running with chmod 777
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ffmpeg'

Comment: Very helpful!

@SRK can you post more details of your setup?  (Had similar issue - double checking my path to ffmpeg solved).